# Aronszajn's criterion for euclidean space, again

Tags: functional-analysis

Referring to the paper [Aronszajn's Criterion for Euclidean Space](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0608) by R.D. Arthan: could someone explain or simplify lemma 3 in all if you are happy to do that? I am in desperate need for that.

My great thanks.

Comment: Who is Brian? Why do you want their explanation, rather than anyone else's? If you just want to talk to one person, why are you using an open Q&A website?

Comment: I’m sorry, but Lemma $3$ is well outside the areas of mathematics with which I’m really comfortable, and it would take me more time than I have to work through it, figure out what’s going on, fill in any missing details in the argument, and then try to explain it. Your first question was different, because I could answer it just by reading the definitions in the paper; this one requires more understanding. I’m going to edit my name out of the question, as I think that doing so will increase the likelihood that someone more knowledgeable will take a look.

Comment: @Chris: It was directed at me, because I answered an earlier, much easier question.

Comment: Please help us to help you. Where does your understanding of the statement or the proof of the lemma start to break down?

Comment: Firstly, in lemma three in the proof it is written that if d=0,1,2, the theorem is trivially true, could you explain how is it trivially please? and this proof is a geometric proof so could you depict it? i mean can you make a graph or anything that make me able to understand?

Answer (score 2):

The theorem states that, if every 2-dimensional subspace of a normed space $V$ is Euclidean, then $V$ is Euclidean. Here "Euclidean" means that the norm is induced by an inner product on $V$. If $V$ is 0- or 1-dimensional, there is only one possible norm (up to a constant factor) and it is Euclidean. If $V$ is 2-dimensional, then it is a 2-dimensional subspace of itself, so the hypothesis of the theorem includes the conclusion. As the proof in the paper says, we then only have the 3-dimensional case left to worry about, because the property of being Euclidean can be expressed using just 3 vector variables and so, if every 3-dimensional subspace of $V$ is Euclidean, then so is $V$.

The picture to have in mind for the 3-dimensional case is a terrestrial globe. We can pick any 2-dimensional subspace of $V$ to act as the plane of the equator. This plane is Euclidean by assumption and we can choose two orthonormal vectors $\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$ in it. The challenge is now to identify a third point $\mathbf{e}_3$ to act as the north (or south) pole and show that the unit sphere of $V$ is a Euclidean sphere with respect to the basis given by $\mathbf{e}_1$, $\mathbf{e}_2$ and $\mathbf{e}_3$. The proof in the paper identifies $\mathbf{e}_3$ using a little bit of convexity theory (namely, the notion of a supporting plane) and shows that $\mathbf{e}_3$ so identified has the required properties.